# Code Works in IntelliJ but Not in Hackerrank Editor

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm doing this question on hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-bubble-sort/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=sorting

I wrote the solution in intellij, and it gives me the correct output there, but when I copied it over to the hackerrank ide, it gave me an error.

This is the code I'm talking about:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class Results {

    /*
     * Complete the 'countSwaps' function below.
     *
     * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY a as parameter.
     */

    public static void countSwaps(List<Integer> a) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        while (!flag) {
            flag = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (a.get(i) > a.get(i + 1)) {
                    int temp = a.get(i);
                    a.set(i, a.get(i + 1));
                    a.set(i + 1, temp);
                    flag = false;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Array is sorted in %d swaps.%n" +
                        "First Element: %d%n" +
                        "Last Element: %d%n",
                count,
                a.get(0),
                a.get(a.size() - 1)));
    }

    public static class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

            List<Integer> a = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .collect(toList());

            Results.countSwaps(a);

            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error: could not find or load main class solution.

Do you have any idea why I'm getting this error here? How could I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online Coding contest platforms generally require you to adhere to certain rules for submissions.

See:  [Sample Problem Statement](https://support.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500009518662)

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Solution
{
  /*
   * Complete the 'countSwaps' function below.
   *
   * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY a as parameter.
   */

  public static void countSwaps (List < Integer > a)
  {
    int count = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    while (!flag)
      {
    flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size () - 1; i++)
      {
        if (a.get (i) > a.get (i + 1))
          {
        int temp = a.get (i);
          a.set (i, a.get (i + 1));
          a.set (i + 1, temp);
          flag = false;
          count++;
          }
      }
      }

    System.out.println (String.format ("Array is sorted in %d swaps.%n" +
                       "First Element: %d%n" +
                       "Last Element: %d%n",
                       count,
                       a.get (0), a.get (a.size () - 1)));
  }

  public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader =
      new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    int n = Integer.parseInt (bufferedReader.readLine ().trim ());

      List < Integer > a =
      Stream.of (bufferedReader.readLine ().replaceAll ("\\s+$",
                            "").split (" ")).
      map (Integer::parseInt).collect (toList ());

      countSwaps (a);

      bufferedReader.close ();
  }
}
```

The `error: could not find or load main class solution.` means your `main()` method in the `Solution` class could not be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

You have put the Solution class within your Result class. HackerRank wants you to put the Solution class as its own class, like this:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class Results {

    /*
     * Complete the 'countSwaps' function below.
     *
     * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY a as parameter.
     */

    public static void countSwaps(List<Integer> a) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        while (!flag) {
            flag = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (a.get(i) > a.get(i + 1)) {
                    int temp = a.get(i);
                    a.set(i, a.get(i + 1));
                    a.set(i + 1, temp);
                    flag = false;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Array is sorted in %d swaps.%n" +
                        "First Element: %d%n" +
                        "Last Element: %d%n",
                count,
                a.get(0),
                a.get(a.size() - 1)));
    }
}

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        List<Integer> a = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(toList());

        Results.countSwaps(a);

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

Please, check your code syntax and read the error that the IDE gives you. It did explicitly tell you that `Error: Could not find or load main class Solution` and just a quick check on the automatic indentation would have shown you the issue.